# Viewer for biomedical 4D image data too large for RAM

Tags: gratis, linux, image-viewer, scientific-computing

I'm currently dealing with 4D microscopy images. Each time step consists of a z-stack of single PNG images. I want to view them and be able to scroll along the z axis as well as the time axis. ImageJ provides exactly that with its ability to concatenate stacks and displaying a window with a slider for time and z position, respectively. However this only works in RAM. Is there another software, or a plugin for a platform such as ImageJ or MeVisLab, that's able to handle larger amounts of data? It has to run on a Ubuntu 16.04 system. Please propose paid software only when there is a free trial version of some sort.

It would be splendid to have a solution in the biomedical context with the possibilites to apply segmentation algorithms etc. The good people at the ImageJ forums have pointed me to the [BigDataViewer plugin](https://imagej.net/BigDataViewer), however this needs the data to be present in .hdf format plus some xml header.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Could you please [edit] your question and add a few details: What Os must it run on, and what is your price limit if it comes to paid software? Also, speaking about "plugin": Where should it plug in to?

Comment: Also how much RAM do you have?  Upgrading to 64 or 128gb isn't that hard, but after that it gets hard.

Comment: @cybernard I have 64GB now and it looks like I'll be allowed to order another 64 :) Why do you say it gets hard above 128?

Comment: Depending on your motherboard, numbers of memory slots, and gigs per slot you could run out of slots.